# installing ubuntu 14.04 in dell inspiron 15

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, system-installation

Whether it  is possible to choose local disc other  than "c" to install ubuntu in dell inspiron.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when installing any Linux (such as Ubuntu) you should refer to their "Linux" device name. "C" is a Microsoft/Windows term for the primary drive (or actually partition). In Linux most modern hard-drives would be named sda (for primary HDD), sdb, sdc, etc. and partition within a specific drive would be sda1, sda2, etc. (for partitions of primary HDD).

So "C" refers to specific partition in your primary drive. Specifically, since you refer to a latop (Dell Inspiron 15) which has an internal space for just one HDD, I assume that you actually mean: "Can I avoid overriding existing data (or OS) that I already have on the partition where my Windows runs?"

You need to tackle two obstacles to make this:

1. Your current "C" drive is probably occupying almost all the free space left on the internal drive. You would need to use a tool like ["Gparted" - booting it from a live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and resizing (Shrinking) the partition that currently holds "C" and making space to create new partition for Ubuntu's  (root) partition.
2. Follow [the instructions pointed by previous answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) in order to install Ubuntu on the new partition you created, and not on the existing partition that holds "C".